# EF CTP5 error: Invalid object name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-ctp5

I followed the example on scottgu's  blog about EF code first CTP5 but I get the error that

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.Products'.

this is the code I got.

```
<add name="CTP5Context"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|EFCTP5.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />


public class CTP5Context : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}



var context = new CTP5Context();
        var products = context.Products;            

        return View(products);
```

im kinda clueless here I done the same as the blogpost, its not my first time with EF (But CTP5 tho), I'm I overlooking something?

Comment: create a connex to that mdf in visual studio and see if there's a Products table.

Answer (score 7):

If your table name is Product in the database, try this:

```
[Table("Product", SchemaName = "dbo")]
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

To use the `Table` attribute You will need to add the following using statement:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Hope this helps! It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Omar. The table attribute fixed my problem. I can only add that instead of SchemaName = "dbo", I had to do Schema="dbo" (SchemaName being unrecognized).

Comment: Thank you Omar! I had just to use Schema instead of Schemaname. You saved my night!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem but I've done 2 changes and it works for me. I changed connection string (Added initial catalog)

```
<add name="CTP5Context"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\northwind.mdf;User Instance=true;initial catalog=Northwind"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and in the Global.asax I've added following line in Application_Start()

```
Database.SetInitializer<Northwind>(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Northwind>());
```

Comment: This is great if your dealing with code first approach, but if you are trying to map to an existing db this won't work.

Answer (score 3):

The exception looks like it's coming from the database.  Are you sure your table name is 'Products' or is it 'Product' (singular instead of plural?)

Comment: I tried both. Usually I could name it plural in the context and singular in database. but now both are plural and no luck.

Comment: Try tracing the SQL.  That error is coming back from the database server, which suggests to me you may be connecting to the wrong database.  What's your connection string?  Is the user you're connecting as configured with the right default database?

Comment: My connectionstring is above. I use the sqlexpress straight from vs studio

Answer (score 3):

It seems EF Code First works differently depending on which type of database you're connecting to.  If you work with SQLCE which is what ScottGu is using to showcase EF Code First, then all tables will be created with names that are not plural.  However, if you use SQL Server 2008 (that's what I tested with), it expected tables names to be plural.  There are  few ways around this, you could add the table name attribute as Omar shows, or you could override the OnModelCreating event for the context.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
 }
```

Comment: This was just perfect for the exact scenario described happened to me. Thanks!

Comment: Note: DbModelBuilder should be ModelBuilder

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your *Products* table was created with the **dbo** Schema, a lot of times  the schema will be something other than **dbo**, such as it can be your username or server name (if the account you're working with isnt in the **db_owner** schema). Open up the DB (since it's SQLExpress) with Server Explorer in Visual Studio)

To do this right click on the table name and select **Open Table Definition** then inside the table definition right click and select **Properties** and in the properties window check what is listed in the **schema** value. If it's not DBO then you should be able to change it to dbo and save it.